# setting the location where pyodbc searches for odbcinst.ini file

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to query ODBC compliant databases using **pyodbc** in **ubuntu**. For that, i have installed the driver (say mysql-odbc-driver). After installation the **odbcinst.ini** file with the configurations gets created in the location **/usr/share/libmyodbc/odbcinst.ini**
When i try to connect to the database using my pyodbc connection code, i get a ***driver not found error message***.
Now when I copy the contents of the file to **/etc/odbcinst.ini**, it works!

This means pyodbc searches for the driver information in file **/etc/odbcinst.ini**.

**How can I change** the location where it searches the odbcinst.ini file for the driver information

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using unixODBC here was some possibilities:

- rebuild unixODBC from scratch and set --sysconfdir
- export ODBCSYSINI  env var pointing to a directory and unixODBC will look here for odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini system dsns
- export ODBCINSTINI and point it at your odbcinst.ini file

BTW, I doubt pyodbc looks anything up in the odbcinst.ini file but unixODBC will. There is a list of ODBC Driver manager APIs which can be used to examine ODBC ini files.