# How do I get Django connecting to SQL Server working with AWS Lambda Layers?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use Django connected to SQL Server 2019 in an AWS Lambda function using Lambda Layers. I found an example using pyodbc to connect to SQL Server here: https://medium.com/@kuharan/aws-lambda-python-ms-sql-server-the-easy-way-e7667d371cc5.
I downloaded the example Lambda Layer and Lambda function and was able to get that working. However, now I am trying to install Django and django-mssql-backend in the layer in order to use Django to connect to SQL Server 2019. Here is a screenshot of how the directory structure is setup with Django and django-mssql-backend installed:

[image]

I zipped up the `pyodbc-layers` folder and uploaded that into Layers. Here is a screenshot of that:

[image]

Then when I run my lambda function, I get the error:

```
Response:  
{  
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'django'",  
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"  
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my function and the error message:

[image]

How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Edit:

Here's all my code as text:

lambda_function.py:

```
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
django.setup()

from models.models import Schedule


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    games = Schedule.objects.using('default').filter(
        game_date=(
            datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
        ).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    ).values()
    
    print(games)
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True

DATABASE_HOSTNAME = 'some_host'
DATABASE_USER = 'some_user'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'some_password'
DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

SECRET_KEY = 'some_key'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = '%Y-%m-%d'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'models',
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': DATABASE_HOSTNAME,
        'USER': DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': DRIVER,
            'isolation_level': 'READ UNCOMMITTED'
        },
    }
}
```

models.models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Schedule(models.Model):
    game_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    game_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'models'
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Schedule'
```

Full error message using this code with the lambda layer build following the directions below:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')",
  "errorType": "InterfaceError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    print(games)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 250, in __repr__\n    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 274, in __iter__\n    self._fetch_all()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 1242, in _fetch_all\n    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 113, in __iter__\n    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py\", line 1092, in results_iter\n    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py\", line 1127, in execute_sql\n    sql, params = self.as_sql()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/compiler.py\", line 177, in as_sql\n    supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py\", line 80, in __get__\n    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py\", line 400, in sql_server_version\n    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py\", line 112, in __enter__\n    return next(self.gen)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 593, in temporary_connection\n    with self.cursor() as cursor:\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 256, in cursor\n    return self._cursor()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py\", line 218, in _cursor\n    conn = super()._cursor()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 233, in _cursor\n    self.ensure_connection()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 217, in ensure_connection\n    self.connect()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py\", line 89, in __exit__\n    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 217, in ensure_connection\n    self.connect()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py\", line 195, in connect\n    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py\", line 314, in get_new_connection\n    timeout=timeout)\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the lambda as text, apart from the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the **custom layer** using [docker tool](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) for `python 3.8`. The instruction are for linux, as I don't have windows to test. Nevertheless, the steps could be adapted to windows.

The **main difficulty** was with **shared libraries** (`libltdl` and `libodbc`) that are required for `odbc`, but are not normally available in lambda environment.

#### Create a layer

The layer will have `django==2.2.12`, `django-mssql-backend` and `pyodbc`.

```
# create layer folder on your host operating system
mkdir /tmp/layer1

# run dcoker container for lambda python 3.8
docker run --rm -v /tmp/layer1:/tmp/layer1 -ti lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 /bin/bash

# in the container exectue the following commands

cd /tmp/layer1
yum install -y unixODBC-devel
python -m venv python
source ./python/bin/activate
pip install django==2.2.12 django-mssql-backend pyodbc
zip -r django-odbc.zip .
cp -rvf /usr/lib64/libltdl.so* .
cp -rvf /usr/lib64/libodbc.so* .
```

Create a layer using django-odbc.zip and remember to set python3.8 as compatible runtime.

#### Create lambda deployment package with your function

To be executed on your host

```
mkdir /tmp/lambda_function
cd /tmp/lambda_function
cp -rvf /tmp/layer1/*.so* .
```

Also add the following the file `lambda_function.py`:

```
import json

import django
import pyodbc 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement 
    
    print(django.get_version())
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Make the deployment package:

```
zip -r lambda_function.zip .
```

Create lambda function using `lambda_function.zip` and add layer `django-odbc.zip` it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added code to my question. I was able to follow your directions and get your test layer and test function working. However, when I try and use your layer with my function, I get this error: `"('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"`. I will add the full error message in my post.

Comment: I think I have to add the `odbc,ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files somewhere in the layer. Where should that be? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I figured it out! I had to merge your instructions with the lambda layer that I downloaded from here: https://github.com/kuharan/Lambda-Layers. I had to copy the python packages EXCEPT the pyodbc package files in the Docker container in `/tmp/layer1/python/lib64/python3.7/site-packages` to the `python` folder in that github layer. Then I zipped that all up and made that a layer in AWS. Then in my lambda function zip, I had to remove all the `lib` files.

Comment: @DiZou Glad to hear it worked out. Thanks for letting me know  about the pyodpc :-)

Comment: I think the reason why I had to use the pyodbc in that github I linked is because the unixODBC library in there is compiled pointing to `/opt` (where the layer gets installedd) to look for `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`. So I think if your instructions are changed to compile unixODBC while looking for the `.ini` files in `/opt`, it would work. There's also an option to set some environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393269/setting-the-location-where-pyodbc-searches-for-odbcinst-ini-file.